# Active Page not working

Tags: html, css, text, css-selectors

Hello I am terribly sorry for the 'easy' question, it's just that I did this verbatim from the website and so I must be missing something painfully obvious. Ok so I have an `li` list and I want the first one to be yellow and the other elements to be white. I have for one of my rules in the real project `li a { color: white` but I am pretty sure that this specific class should override that rule, no? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
 

.active{
 color: yellow;
}


#subnav {
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#subnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 
}

#subnav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#subnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#subnav li a:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
<div id="subnav">


<ul> 
 

        <li> <a class="active" href="#overview">Overview </a></li>
         



      </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a problem or want an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a more specific css selector to override the white color coming from `#subnav li a` like below:

```
#subnav li a.active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

and you will have the first `li` yellow if you have put `active` class to it.

```css
.active {
  color: yellow;
}
#subnav {
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
#subnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#subnav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#subnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav li a.active {
  color: yellow;
}
#subnav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="subnav">

  <ul>
    <li> <a class="active" href="#overview">Overview </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#test">Test </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work. Thanks

```
#subnav li a:hover,
#subnav li a.active {
   color: yellow;
}
```